# Discord.py rewrite not return cached image

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

i write simple cod:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_message_delete(self, ctx):
    if ctx.cached_message.author.bot is False:

        embed=discord.Embed(title='Deleted message:', description=ctx.cached_message.content, color=0xff00f6)
        embed.set_author(name = ctx.cached_message.author, icon_url=ctx.cached_message.author.avatar_url)

        embed.set_image(url = ctx.cached_message.attachments[0].url)
        await ctx.cached_message.channel.send(embed = embed)
```

and this code didn't set image because it was access denied response. Image url response(if I go to url):

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied.</Message>
<Details>Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.</Details>
</Error>
```

how can I send cached image?

p.s. I know there is a error in this code if attachments is None.

Answer (score 1):

i replace `ctx.cached_message.attachments[0].url` to `ctx.cached_message.attachments[0].proxy_url` and it work.